# R8 Missing android.view Class Warnings

Tags: android, xamarin, crash, android-r8

I have recently starting seeing the following three errors during release builds using the R8 code shrinker:

> R8 : warning : Missing class: android.view.WindowInsetsAnimationControlListener

> R8 : warning : Missing class: android.view.WindowInsetsController$OnControllableInsetsChangedListener

> R8 : warning : Missing class: android.view.WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback

The build completes and the app runs but I suspect that this is the cause of a number of crashes I've started to see on Google Play Console. I haven't been able to reproduce these crashes on my own devices (or emulator). From the limited stack trace they don't appear to be anything to do with my own code (I've included an example stack trace at the bottom of this post). That the stack trace appears to show an error related to view creation/rendering, and the R8 errors relate to android.view, is why I suspect they're related (that and the fact that they both started appearing at the same time...).

I've found a number of posts and bug reports related to R8 missing class warnings but nothing specific to these three and nothing that really helps. I've tried adding lines like the following to proguard.cfg but it hasn't helped.

> -keep class android.view.** { *; }

Is anyone able to shed light on the problem?

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00083] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000d3] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00033] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) [0x0003e] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) [0x000c4] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) [0x0016c] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) [0x00007] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000f0] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00033] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) [0x0003e] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ScrollViewContainer.set_ChildView (Xamarin.Forms.View value) [0x00041] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ScrollViewRenderer.LoadContent () [0x00011] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ScrollViewRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x000cf] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) [0x0003e] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) [0x000c4] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) [0x0016c] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) [0x00007] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000f0] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00033] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager, Android.Content.Context context) [0x00031] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FragmentContainer.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0001b] in <2e0d929b7f78480c8db42fc55cca561c>:0
at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_inflater, System.IntPtr native_container, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00020] in <4e81a5c29660454fa4f16aaaa8f6f3d0>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.51(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.FragmentContainer.n_onCreateView (Native Method)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.FragmentContainer.onCreateView (Unknown Source)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Unknown Source:15)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (Unknown Source:179)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (Unknown Source:237)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (Unknown Source:2)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState (Unknown Source:58)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (Unknown Source:47)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (Unknown Source:186)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps (Unknown Source:38)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (Unknown Source:119)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (Unknown Source:84)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (Unknown Source:21)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run (Unknown Source:3)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8057)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:656)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Comment: Can you try to create new blank project, release build to see whether there are this problem here.

Comment: Aye, that was on my to do list but I wanted to post the problem first in case anyone else had come across the problem. It might take me a while if it's a specific plugin or something that triggers the issue. I've created a fresh project now and it builds okay, so now I'm adding in NuGet packages one-by-one to see if it breaks. It's a faff because I have to do something to use each one otherwise, if it is a linker problem, it might not be triggered just because the plugin is installed.

Comment: After a few hours of trial and error with a new blank project, I've narrowed it down to Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView. I don't get the errors with version 1.2.0 but I do with versions 1.2.1 and 1.2.1.1. Changing the version of this NuGet package appears to be the only thing that makes a difference, so it must be a new bug. I'm going to open a bug on VS Feedback.

Comment: You mean that you have this error message when using **Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView 1.2.1**, but using **Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView 1.2.0**, project has no problem, it works fine?

Comment: That's right, aye. With a fresh Xamarin.Forms template solution, and deploying a release build to the emulator, I get these warnings with Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView version 1.2.1. With version 1.2.1.1 I get these warnings and the app crashes immediately on startup. With 1.2.0 the app builds and runs okay on the emulator.

Comment: don't know how do you use Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, but I download `Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView 1.2.1` in `Xamarin.forms 5.0 version`, and deploying release build, having no problem.

Comment: Same issue here with Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView

Comment: Same occurrs bumping from **androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0** to **androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0** or **1.3.1**:
- Missing class: android.view.WindowInsetsAnimationControlListener
- Missing class: android.view.WindowInsetsController$OnControllableInsetsChangedListener
- Missing class: android.view.WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback

Comment: In case of these warnings is it safe to ignore them or is it better to disable R8?

Comment: @Costas, I'm not sure it's safe to ignore them as the issue may be the cause of some crashes. You might not get the crashes though as they might result from some interaction. So I would suggest the options are either to disable R8 (which means your app will be unnecessarily large), or use an older version of RecyclerView which doesn't lead to the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and it kept same even by Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView 1.2.0.
Nuget package version relation is too complex.
It becomes OK by "Code shrinker" setting "R8" to blank. (This fact should be already clear all person committing this discussion.)
I think no perfect solution outside of omitting R8.

Comment: That's not really a solution to the problem though, not using a code shrinker. A code shrinker is necessary to minimise the size of the app, which itself is critically important to mobile app deployment.